# Table of contents -- changing headings

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I use `\tableofcontents` to generate a ToC of a book. It uses Roman numerals I, II, III for parts, and Arabic numerals 1, 2, 3 for chapters. I would like it to say "Part I" rather than "I", and "Chapter 23" rather than "23". How can I change this consistently throughout the document?

Comment: AFAIR `tocloft` can do this

Comment: @daleif: Can you not port the memoir toc setup to `toclof`. It does not look if Peter Wilson is going to get around to do that.  This is a very old FAQ and there are not realy a good solution besides memoir and amsbook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package. A little example (feel free to adapt it according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
    \newlength\mylenprt
    \newlength\mylenchp
    \newlength\mylenapp

    \renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{\partname~}
    \renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~}
    \renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}

    \settowidth\mylenprt{\cftpartfont\cftpartpresnum\cftpartaftersnum}
    \settowidth\mylenchp{\cftchapfont\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
    \settowidth\mylenapp{\cftchapfont\appendixname~\cftchapaftersnum}
    \addtolength\mylenprt{\cftpartnumwidth}
    \addtolength\mylenchp{\cftchapnumwidth}
    \addtolength\mylenapp{\cftchapnumwidth}

    \setlength\cftpartnumwidth{\mylenprt}
    \setlength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylenchp}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter

    \part{First Part}
    \chapter{First Chapter}

    \appendix
    \addtocontents{toc}{% NB!!! must be inside the first \include
        \protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchappresnum{\appendixname~}%
        \protect\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\mylenapp}}%

    \chapter{First Appendix}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: changed the "manual" names "Part" and "Chapter" to \partname and "\chaptername".

EDIT: changed to properly handle appendixes

Comment: And what about appendixes?

Comment: @Danie Els: you are right; I've edited my code to use `\partname` and `\chaptername` which should handle appendices if the `\backmatter` command is used.

Comment: Nope, you have redefine `\cftchappresnum` inside a `\addtocontents`.  This causes a new set of problems when you use `\include` because of latex's immediate and delayed write mechanisms.  The only foolproof solution is `memoir` or `amsbook`

Comment: Typo in comment. Should have been: you have to redefine ....