# How to get the word "Part" in contents

Tags: table-of-contents

when I use the \part command, in table of contents I get roman numerals followed by the title of the part. For example: "III Title of the third part". I would like to have the word "Part" followed by roman numerals and then by the title, e.g. "Part III Title of the third part". How can I get it?

Thank you!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17863/113546

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I report the solution so it can be useful for others.
I have used the package tocloft, and I have written the following line:

\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{Part\hspace{0.5em}}